# The "C:\xampp\tmp\phpE189.tmp" file does not exist or is not readable. in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

Please help me.
i want insert image into folder and data into database.
I tried many ways but still failed.
I copied a piece of code and successfully run another function.

my controller

```
 public function postThem(Request $req) {
        $this->validate($req,
            [
            ],
            [
            ]
            ); 
        $chitiet = new chitiet();
        $chitiet->tengame=$req->tengame;
        $chitiet->idnhaphathanh=$req->idnhaphathanh;
        $chitiet->idtheloai=$req->idtheloai;
        $chitiet->idcauhinh=$req->idcauhinh;
        $chitiet->namphathanh=$req->namphathanh;
        $chitiet->mota=$req->mota;
        $chitiet->nentang=$req->nentang;
        $chitiet->link=$req->link;
        $chitiet->link2=$req->link2;
        if($req->hasFile('anhbia'))
        {
            $file=$req->file('anhbia');
            $duoi=$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            if($duoi!='jpg'){
                return redirect()->back()->with('ok','Chỉ đc thêm ảnh có đuôi jpg nhé');
            }
            $name=$req->tengame.".jpg";
            $req->file('anhbia')->move('sources/image',
                $name);
            $chitiet->anhbia=$name;
        } else {
            echo 'failese';
        }

        if($req->hasFile('anh1'))
        {
            $file=$req->file('anh1');
            $duoi=$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            if($duoi!='jpg'){
                return redirect()->back()->with('ok','Chỉ đc thêm ảnh có đuôi jpg nhé');
            }
            $name=$req->tengame."1".".jpg";
            $file->move("sources/image",
                $name);
            $chitiet->anh1=$name;
        } else {
            echo 'failese';
        }

        if($req->hasFile('anh2'))
        {
            $file=$req->file('anh2');
            $duoi=$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            if($duoi!='jpg'){
                return redirect()->back()->with('ok','Chỉ đc thêm ảnh có đuôi jpg nhé');
            }
            $name=$req->tengame."2".".jpg";
            $file->move("sources/image",
                $name);
            $chitiet->anh2=$name;
        } else {
            echo 'failese';
        }

        if($req->hasFile('anh3'))
        {
            $file=$req->file('anh3');
            $duoi=$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            if($duoi!='jpg'){
                return redirect()->back()->with('ok','Chỉ đc thêm ảnh có đuôi jpg nhé');
            }
            $name=$req->tengame."3".".jpg";
            $file->move("sources/image",
                $name);
            $chitiet->anh3=$name;
        } else {
            echo 'failese';
        }
        $chitiet->video=$req->video;
        $chitiet->luottai="0";
        $chitiet->save();
        return redirect()->back()->with('ok','Thêm game thành công :v');
```

my view

```
<form action="admin/chitiet/them" method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tên game" name="tengame" size="10" value="" require="true">
        <br>
        <select class="form-control match-content" name="idnhaphathanh">
            @foreach($nph as $nph)
            <option value="{{$nph->idnhaphathanh}}">{{$nph->tennhaphathanh}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <br>
        <select class="form-control match-content" name="idtheloai">
            @foreach($theloai as $tl)
            <option value="{{$tl->idtheloai}}">{{$tl->tentheloai}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <br>
        <select class="form-control match-content" name="idcauhinh">
            @foreach($cauhinh as $ch)
            <option value="{{$ch->idcauhinh}}">{{$ch->os}}, {{$ch->cpu}}, {{$ch->gpu}}, {{$ch->ram}}, {{$ch->storage}}
            </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <br>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="namphathanh" min="2000" max="2019" step="1" value="2019"
            maxlength="4">
        <br>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Mô tả game" name="mota"></textarea>
        <br>
        <select class="form-control match-content" name="nentang">
            <option selected="">PC</option>
            <option>Mobile</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Link" size="10" value="" name="link">
        <br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Link dự phòng" size="10" value="" name="link2">
        <br>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="anhbia" id="anhbia">
        <br>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="anh1">
        <br>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="anh2">
        <br>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="anh3">
        <br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Video" size="10" value="" name="video">
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" width="30%">Thêm</button>
    </form>
```

yesterday,  it's working, but now error occur:

> The "C:\xampp\tmp\phpE189.tmp" file does not exist or is not readable.

I run the code, the image was put into the directory, but the data was not and there was an error.
thanks

Comment: can you show the code of view file?

Comment: Do you mean the image is uploaded successfully in the "sources/image" folder?

Comment: image already upload successfully, but the error still appears

Comment: @BhavinThummar i already show view file

Comment: wich version of laravel do you are using ? have you done a laravel migration to version 6 ? see too here to clear caches : https://tecadmin.net/clear-cache-laravel-5/

Comment: comment  your code and show us the line causing the error

Comment: @Modric Do you want to debug your code to add exist and found on exact line where the error is generated?

Comment: It's data greather than 2Mb ? check data size you send, and compare with upload_max_filesize and  post_max_size in php.ini

Comment: @Eric 4 file I insert <100 kb

Comment: @BhavinThummar please help me

Comment: @Eric i use laravel 6.4.1 when i start project

Comment: @Modric you have to check the code after image upload to add exit function after a line by line and check when that error is stopping to show. So we can find out which function or line give this error.

Comment: @Modric have you tried doing php artisan view:clear and also php artisan config:cache

Comment: @BhavinThummar My code is above, please give an example

Comment: @KhalidKhan I already tried but can not

Comment: @Modric Okay. Can you create this file phpE189.tmp file in that folder

Comment: @KhalidKhan  where to create that file?

Comment: In this path C:\xampp\tmp\

Comment: yes, in that folder  not available thì file

Comment: I think the error occurs at $xxx->save(); try to put a dd($chitiet); just before the "save" and show us the contents of this variable when it is displayed.

Comment: you can catch error too  : try { code... $xxx->save(); .. code } (\Exception $e) {
  dd($e);
}